# Splitting a CSV Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, csv, split

I have a string like

```
 Query_1,ab563372363_C/R,100.00,249,0,0,1,249,1,249,1e-132, 460
 Query_1,ab563372356_C/R,99.60,249,1,0,1,249,1,249,5e-131, 455
```

in a file
in two separate lines. I am reading it from the textbox. I have to output ab563372363_C/R and ab563372356_C/R in a text box. I am trying to use the split function for that but its not working..

```
Dim splitString as Array
results = "test.txt"
Dim FileText As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(results)  'reads the above contents from file
splitString = Split(FileText, ",", 14)
TextBox2.text = splitString(1) & splitString(13)
```

for the above code, it just prints the whole thing.. What's wrong?

Comment: Use the TextFieldParser class, it was made to do this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant very cool! Never knew about this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First

Since you are reading the whole text, your `FileText` would be ending like this:

```
Query_1,ab563372363_C/R,100.00,249,0,0,1,249,1,249,1e-132,460
\r\n
Query_1,ab563372356_C/R,99.60,249,1,0,1,249,1,249,5e-131, 455
```

So when you are referencing to your `splitString`with those indexes (**1**, **13**) your result might probably be wrong.

## Second

Try to specify what kind of type your array is, `Dim splitString as Array` should be `Dim splitString As String()`

## Third

Make your code more readable/maintainable and easy to edit (not only for you, but others)

## The Code

```
Private const FirstIndex = 1
Private const SecondIndex = 12

Sub Main
    Dim myDelimiter As Char

    Dim myString As String
    Dim mySplit As String()

    Dim myResult1 As String
    Dim myResult2 As String

    myDelimiter = ","

    myString += "Query_1,ab563372363_C/R,100.00,249,0,0,1,249,1,249,1e-132, 460"
    myString += "Query_1,ab563372356_C/R,99.60,249,1,0,1,249,1,249,5e-131, 455"

    mySplit = myString.Split(myDelimiter)

    myResult1 = mySplit(FirstIndex)
    myResult2 = mySplit(SecondIndex)

    Console.WriteLine(myResult1)
    Console.WriteLine(myResult2)
End Sub
```

Comment: The question was to read from a file on disk, not from a predefined concatenated string. This may work, but it's not very robust if more strings needed to be added, which is likely

Comment: @Ric, as I pointed out (if you read the whole post) he's using **ReadAllText** that would return "Line#1\r\nLine#2", that's what I coded that way. Besides my code is an explanation not a working example that'll try to fit his needs.

Comment: fair play, didn't mean to offend! Apologies :)

Comment: @Ric: No worries, I wasn't trying to be rude. Cheers guy :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Private Function GetRequiredText() As List(Of String)
    Dim requiredStringList As New List(Of String)
    Dim file = "test.txt"
    If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(file) Then

        Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(file)
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        While line IsNot Nothing
            requiredStringList.Add(line.Split(",")(1))
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        End While

        reader.Close()
        reader.Dispose()
    End If
    Return requiredStringList
End Function
```

This will read the file line by line and add the item you require to a list of strings which will be returned by the function.

Returning a List(Of String) may be overkill, but it's quite simple to illustrate and to work with.

You can then iterate through the list and do what you need with the contents of the list.

Comments welcome!!

Also this might work...

```
Dim query = From lines In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file) _
                    Select lines.Split(",")(1)
```

this will return an IEnumerable(Of String)

Enjoy

Comment: +1 for pointing out many ways to complete this task (Functions & Generics, LINQ)

Comment: cheers!! just thought of another way with less lines of code:    Dim query = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(Function(f) f.Split(",")(1))